# Facebook Graph API responds with "This application has surpassed the limit of test accounts"

Tags: rest, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect a page to my Facebook business app.
When I hit the following endpoint [GET] /v17.0/{user-id}/accounts HTTP/1.1 I get the following response:

```
{
    "data": []
}
```

From what I understood this means that the app does not have any pages.

Also is there a way to do this via the dashboard?
Thanks in advance :)

If I send a post request on \[POST\] /v17.0/{user-id}/accounts HTTP/1.1 with the page I want to add I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#2900) This application has surpassed the limit of test accounts",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2900,
        "fbtrace_id": "A-e9Y36dI1UpQ0XHxyJUWso"
    }
}
```

The application is in live mode, so I am unsure why does it require test accounts ?